# Which database is best suited for store GRID data?

Tags: database

We work with meteorology data in grid files. Each file is a 2d-array of latitude longitude grid of some meteo parameter (presepetaton, temperature or wind). We need to store this grid files in DB for making requests for given coordinates. Which database is best suited for this?

In details: Every grid file have lat-lon grid. For example, grid with dimension 0.25 degree: 4 points per degree, so its 180 * 4 = 720 per 360 * 4 = 1440 points. Or it is 1 036 800 points with values. Value - it is some meteo parameter: temperature, pressure, rain, cloud intensity. Every parameter is inside a weather model - gfs, ecmwf, etc. End every model recalculate every 3 hours. So we have a model-param-timestamp-grid data model. Our api have method for request param in given coords, model and timestamp.